# Remove hover with on()

Tags: jquery

I would like to have both a hover and remove hover event.  The nodes which have this event are added dynamically, so I wish to use on().  When adding a hover event, it works great (the #second list below).  For some reason when I add the off hover event, not even the add hover event will work (#first list below).

Please provide any clues.  A live example is located at http://jsfiddle.net/NV7hR/

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#first").on("hover", "a", function(event) {
    $(this).parent().css("background-color", "yellow");
  }, function(event) {
    $(this).parent().css("background-color", "");
  });
  $("#second").on("hover", "a", function(event) {
    $(this).parent().css("background-color", "yellow");
  });
});

<body>
<ul id="first">
    <li><a href="#"/>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"/>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"/>Link</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="second">
    <li><a href="#"/>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"/>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"/>Link</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: `.hover` is shorthand form of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. Hover as such is not an event. And .on('hover'.. is not a valid syntax.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/hover/ it's all there... RTFM!

Comment: @Niko You cannot use hover with .on(). If user1032531 wants to use .on(), they have to split it into mouseenter and mouseleave. Alternately, you can use the .hover() directly.

Comment: @SKS: Why do you think `.on('hover'...` isn't valid syntax?

Comment: @amnotiam Actually 'valid syntax' is not the correct word there.. the way he used is not correct. He used it assuming it is same as .hover api which is not the case.

Comment: Okay, I was incorrect that you can use hover with .on(), but it is not applicable to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the hover into mouseenter and mouseleave, which is what hover is shorthand for anyways.

```
$("#first").on("mouseenter", "a", function(event) {
   $(this).parent().css("background-color", "yellow");
}).on("mouseleave", "a", function(event) {
   $(this).parent().css("background-color", "");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`.hover` as such is not an event. `hover` is shorthand for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. Try using like below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/NV7hR/2/)

```
$("#first").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).parent().css("background-color", "yellow");
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).parent().css("background-color", "");
    }
}, 'a');
```

Answer (score 2):

In spite of what everyone else claims, you can indeed use `'hover'` with `.on()`.

It's just that you can't pass 2 functions. You need to test the event type.

```
$("#first").on("hover", "a", function(e) {
    $(this).css("background-color", e.type === 'mouseenter' ? "yellow" : '');
});
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/HxuuS/

---

FYI, the reason passing 2 functions caused it to not work at all is that the first handler was interpreted as the optional `data` argument to `on`, so it was only the second handler *(the `mouseleave` one)* that was being bound.

Comment: I don't see the point of using the `hover` shorthand when you have to test the mouse event anyway.

Comment: @Sparky672: There are situations where it makes sense. For example, if I was using `.toggleClass()` instead of `.css()`. Even given the above example, it's still less code than assigning separate handlers.